# Run Rules automatically on schedule to move mail from public email box

Tags: vba, outlook

Trying to run a rule to move emails upon arrival from first public email box to second public email box.

Rule is: Apply this rule after the message arrives | Sent to "first public email box" | move it to the "second public email box" folder.

Rule works when run manually but the rule does not work automatically upon emails arriving (research shows there might be some corrupt file, ...).

Trying to make it work via VBA instead.  Below macro supposed to run the rules upon a reminder popping up.  Reminder pops up, but rules don't run.

Running that macro from a QAT custom button, brings up progress window, and that window shows progress, but emails are still in the first public email box.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Task" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

If Item.Subject = "Run Rules" Then
  RunRules
End If

End Sub

Sub RunRules()

Dim olRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim myRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim olRuleNames() As Variant
Dim name As Variant

olRuleNames = Array("Rule A", "Rule B")

Set olRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()

For Each name In olRuleNames()
    For Each myRule In olRules
    ' Rules we want to run
        If myRule.name = name Then
        myRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of DefaultStore is a hint there are stores other than the default.

`Set olRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FindStoreWithRules()

Dim colStores As stores
Dim oStore As store

Dim olRules As rules
Dim myRule As Rule

Dim i As Long

Set colStores = Session.stores

For i = 1 To colStores.count

    Debug.Print i & ": " & colStores(i)

    ' On second run
    ' Enter applicable name then uncomment this line and the End If
    ' If colStores(i) = "Name of store shown in immediate window" Then

        On Error Resume Next
        ' Where rules not applicable on some stores there is an error.
        Set olRules = colStores(i).GetRules()
        ' Discontinue error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not olRules Is Nothing Then
            For Each myRule In olRules
                ' Uncomment on second run to see if what rules were found
                'Debug.Print " - " & myRule.name
            Next
        Else
            Debug.Print "Rules not applicable in " & colStores(i)
        End If

    ' End If

Next

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: On the first run in Immediate window it printed 11 mailbox names, one is mine and 10 Public. Under one that I am trying to automate running the rules it printed "Rules not applicable in Public Folders - ABC@domain.com" On line: Debug.Print i & ": " & colStores(i) – it gave “Run-time error’-2147024891 (80070005)’: You do not have sufficient permission to perform this operation on this object. See the folder contact or your system administrator.” Am I to interpret all that as what I am trying to accomplish is not possible?

Comment: I cannot comment on your permissions. You will have to investigate how you are set up in Outlook. One thing I try to mention on code that fails for shared "mailboxes". Try adding an account if you have only a mailbox http://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1507